# Clearing up conceptual understanding of React components, Higher Order Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have a conceptual question regarding React. My level is fairly advanced, but today I came across a situation and I'm not sure if my intuition is correct.

> The tldr question is: Is it weird to have a function that takes in
>   props parameter and returns a React component? My motivation for doing
>   so is that I want different configurations of a particular React
>   component.
>
> One of the main motivations for this problem is due to Flow typing.
>   If you look at my example below, if I just define a single component with InputProps & Props, when I configure the component with just the "InputProps", flow will complain and say I haven't provided Props. But the problem is that I don't intend to pass in props until this "configured" component is passed into another component.
>
> Can this be considered a functional stateless component because it takes in props and returns a React element? I'm assuming a React component count as a React element
>
> I know that this is not a higher-order component (HOC), because a HOC
>   is a function that takes in a component and returns a new component -
>   this is not what's going on here.

The context for why I would want to do this is that I have a component that takes in a prop, let's call it `myLovelyProp`. `myLovelyProp` is a `React.Component`. `myLovelyProp` itself takes in various props. I have 10 or so various configurations of `myLovelyProp`, so I want a function that can quickly configure these various cases.

Here's the general markup of what I'm thinking of. In the example below, `InputProps` are the props that my function takes. `Props` are the props of `MyLovelyComponent` - they will be injected when `MyLovelyComponent` is used, but not when it's configured.

```
type InputProps = {
    prop1: string,
    prop2: string,
}

type Props = {
    propA: string,
    propB: string,
}

export default function(props: InputProps): React.ComponentType<Props> {
    return class MyLovelyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
        ...
        render = () => {
            return (
               <StuffThatNeedsProp1 var1={prop1}>
               <StuffThatNeedsProp2 var1={prop2}>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: currently you don't return component rather declaring class inside. but even if you returned component as a result it'd be strange to have class declared inside the function.  you will never be able to reuse it somewhere else.

Comment: @skyboyer - Thanks for pointing out the fact I didn't return the component - just fixed that. I don't need to re-use the component inside the function, I just need to be able to use the one that's returned. Also, let me edit the question to explain that one main motivation for this is because of flow typing issues

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand what is your challenge. if prop is required then how could you avoid passing it? if props is not required - why don't you mark it as optional? if you have different versions of `type Props` where depending on case you need different props required and for other case they should be just skipped - then you can declare type as `type Props = PropsConfig1 | PropsConfig2`. Please be more specific on challenge itself.

Comment: As in the example, InputProps and Props are both required of the component. However, InputProps are passed in at the time of configuration, and Props are injected later when another component uses it. Does this help? Flow doesn't know that I'm passing in props at two different times, however, and so it will complain if I don't pass them all in at the same time, unless I do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you need to preconfigure some component with set of props at one place and later provide it with additional props at different place right? Then you can use function that returns HOC

```
function preconfigure(Component, propsToPreconfigure) {
    return additionalProps => (<Component {...propsToPreconfigure} {...additionalProps} />);
}

//...
const PreconfiguredWithAB = preconfigure(MyLovelyComponent, {a: 'preset1', b: 'preset2'});
//...
<PreconfiguredWithAB d="2" e="4" />
```

It is not much better than you variant but it's generic and also it allows to store intermediate class as a variable for reuse.